# Which api documentation should be used when developing for Android in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm, documentation

Unfortunately i'm new in Kotlin (hate this language), and i am so confused that i can't understand which documentation should i use (since Kotlin also runs on JVM)
For example i want to look at *ArrayList* documentation.
Which one of the two links should i use:

[Android site](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/ArrayList)

[Kotlin site](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/)

In addition why *ArrayList* is defined differently in both sites? one include **Any**

Hope someone can help me to solve this confusion

Comment: "Which one of the two links should i use" -- both, probably, though the Kotlin one is a superset. Roughly speaking, the sections of the Kotlin `ArrayList` documentation for [extension properties](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/#extension-properties) and [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/#extension-functions) are added by Kotlin.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the answer but i'm sorry. I didn't understand it at all :(

Comment: You might want to read up on [Kotlin extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html). Kotlin allows developers to add new properties and functions to existing classes, without creating a subclass. See also [this Klassbook example](https://klassbook.commonsware.com/lessons/Extension%20Functions/extfn.html) or any decent book on Kotlin programming.

Comment: I'm learning from a book:"Head First Kotlin". It doesn't talk on api's at all

Comment: This has nothing to do with an API. If "Head First Kotlin" covers extension functions and extension properties, re-read that chapter.

Comment: @CommonsWare, i started to read (it is in the end of the book) soon. But can you help me to understand: 1. Are all those extensions are supported when coding for android application? 2. Why in Kotlin site it is written **typealias ArrayList<E> = ArrayList<E>** when in android site it is written class ArrayList<E : Any!>. i'm talking on E against E:Any!  (inside braces)

Comment: "Are all those extensions are supported when coding for android application?" -- yes. For 2, what you copied from "android site" is being a bit more formal. In both cases, they are saying that you can create an `ArrayList` of any object type. In Kotlin, `Any` is the base class from which all other classes inherit. In generics notation, `ArrayList<E>` and `ArrayList<E : Any>` are equivalent. The `!` is a designation of a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) and indicates that we do not know whether it could be `null` or not.

Comment: first of all thank you for the explanation .I came with java knowledge so i know generics  and inheritence,  etc. But i must say that **ArrayList<E : Any>** is very confusing (What is the type? E or Any), and can't understand why it is written differently in both documentation? If you are an android developer, can you suggest me which document should be my favorite one in order to make my life easier?

Comment: "I came with java knowledge so i know generics" -- the syntax for generics is the same in Java and Kotlin. "What is the type? E or Any" -- `Any` is the upper bound for the type, the same as it is in Java. "and can't understand why it is written differently in both documentation?" -- it was written by two different teams. Since `Any` is the default upper bound (just as `Object` is in Java), `: Any` is optional. One team decided to include it, one team did not.

Comment: I have never show in Java something like Object E? only using question mark and the *super* keyword when using generics

Comment: Kotlin syntax for generic types is different than in Java: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html